# Backpropagation on a CNN

Tags: convolutional-neural-network, matlab, ai

I have tried searching for this, but it seems like no one addresses a key aspect of this problem (or maybe I'm overthinking this):

So, first let's assume we have a 3x3 image with a single channel, and we apply a 2x2 kernel to it, and let's name the kernel weights $w_1$, $w_2$, $w_3$ and $w_4$. This convolution generates a 2x2 feature map, and let's name the resulting activations $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ and $a_4$.

So, the way you would calculate the activations would be something like:

$\sigma(w_1 * v_1 + w_2 * v_2 + w_3 * v_4 + w_4 * v_5 + b) = a_1$

$\sigma(w_1 * v_2 + w_2 * v_3 + w_3 * v_5 + w_4 * v_6 + b) = a_2$

...

Now, my question is:

To calculate dw1, you'd have different results in each activation (dw1 in a1 = v1, whereas dw1 in a2 = v2). So for these, do you **SUM** them, or **AVERAGE** them? I've tried it both ways, and averaging them has gotten me faster training and better results, but it seems like most people tell you to sum?

Here's a code snippet of how I'm implementing this (data is shaped this way because i'm performing convolution through matrix multiplication and index manipulation)

**dz** is the activation derivative to the current layer, and they all have the following shape:

(number of kernels, feature map size, batch size)

```matlab
            data = squeeze(sum(data, 2)); // MEAN or SUM across feature maps
            db = squeeze(sum(dz, 2)); // MEAN or SUM across feature maps
            dw = db * data';
            db = sum(db, 2); // Definitely SUM all mini-batch values
```